# pointers increment in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   static char *s[]={"black","white","pink","violet"};
   char **ptr[]={s+3,s+2,s+1,s},***p;
   char a[]={"DEAD"};
   p=ptr;
   ++p;
   printf("%c\n",a[0]);
   printf("%s\n",*s); //black 
   printf("%s\n",*s+1); //lack
   //printf("%s\n",s+1);
   printf("%s\n",s[0]);//black   
   printf("%s\n",s[1]);//white
   printf("%s\n",s[2]);//pink
   printf("%s\n",s[1]);//violet
   printf("%s\n",s[1]+1);//hite
   printf("%s\n",s[1]+6);//pink
   printf("%s\n",**p+1); // how does this prints ink
   return 0;
}
```

output:

> D black lack black white pink white hite pink ink

please help to understand

Comment: `char a[] = {"DEAD"};` looks suspicious

Comment: @knittl: `char a[] = {"DEAD"};` is ok: the `{}` are redundant, not suspicious :-)

Comment: @pmg: my understanding of array initializers in C is a bit rusty, but I would expect either an array of chars to be initialized with `={'c'}`, or an array of char pointers with `={"DEAD"}`.

Comment: I think it's a special case of array with a single element (couldn't find the relevant passage in the Standard). It's just as "suspicious" as `int i = {42};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have no problem with lines I haven't directly copied

```
printf("%s\n",*s+1); //lack
```

`*s+1` is the same as `(*s) + 1`

```
printf("%s\n",s[1]+6);//pink
```

`s[1]+6` is the same as `(s[1]) + 6`. `s[1]` has type `char*`, so `s[1]+6` points 6 characters to the right. **But it's illegal to do that**: `s[1]` only points to 6 valid characters. You just had (bad) luck that your program didn't crash.

```
printf("%s\n",**p+1); // how does this prints ink
```

*approximately the same things go for `**p+1` :)*

Answer (score 4):

so, p is a pointer to a pointer to a string, which basically is a pointer to a char.

p itself points to the first element of the ptr array; after `p++` it points to the second, which is s+2.

s+2 points to the third element in the s array, which is "pink"

these are the two levels od dereferencing performed by `**p`

now, `**p` points to the first character of "pink", thus `**p+1` points to the 'i'

now, printf takes the pointer to the i and prints everything until the next null byte, resulting in "ink" being printed to your console.

Answer (score 2):

```
p = ptr;
++p; /* p now points to the second element of ptr "s+2" */
/* s+2 points to the third element of s "pink" */
/* **p+1 will point to the second character of "pink", thus "ink"; essentially **(s+2)+1 */
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand pointers.

`s[0]` is exactly the same as `*s`.

If you have `s[0]+1`, it points one char further than `s[0]`.

`s[1]` is the same as `*(s+1)`, but it is completely different from `*s+1`, which is the same as `s[0]+1`.

You have to draw arrows on a blackboard.